# Transforming from Stax to DOM results in NullPointerException

Tags: java, stax

I am using StAX to reading through XML content and parsing parts of it into DOM fragments by transforming from StAXSource to DOMResult. However, this results in NullPointerException when any element re-defines default XML namespace (xmlns=""). Minimal code to demonstrate the situation:

```
String xml =
  "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>"+
  "<document>"+
  "  <element xmlns=\"\" />"+
  "</document>";

StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml);
XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(reader);

TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer t = tf.newTransformer();

StAXSource source = new StAXSource(xsr);
DOMResult result = new DOMResult();

t.transform(source,result);
```

The beginning of stacktrace is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.NamespaceMappings.pushNamespace(NamespaceMappings.java:233)
  at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToXMLSAXHandler.startPrefixMapping(ToXMLSAXHandler.java:362)...
```

In my understanding the input XML is valid. Woodstox implementation transforms the XML without problems but I would prefer not add more dependencies to my app if there is way to configure or work around the problem with default implementation bundled with Java. Is there any way? Or should this be considered bug in Java default implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Use valid xml file

**Try to change your code**

```
   XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
          XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(new FileReader("test.xml"));
            xsr.nextTag(); 

            TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer t = tf.newTransformer();
            while(xsr.nextTag() == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT) {
                DOMResult result = new DOMResult();
                t.transform(new StAXSource(xsr), result);
                Node domNode = result.getNode();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use SAX, works fine even with xmlns = ""

```
XMLReader xr = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
Source source = new SAXSource(xr, new InputSource(reader));
```